# Finding a one sided limit algebraically (not plugging in numbers)

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm looking for a way to determine a one sided limit algebraically, such as

$$\color{blue}{f(x) = \frac {|x|}{x} , x \neq 0}$$

I know that you can find the limit by plugging in numbers or graphing it, but there must be a way to find it without using either of those as a crutch.

Comment: Use the definition of $|x|$ as a piecewise function. Of course, there is no limit for $|x|/x$ as $x$ approaches zero.

Comment: thank you! I can't believe I missed that

Comment: and what about equations such as lim(x->-2 from the left) of 1/(x+2)^2

Comment: Well, in that case, the limit diverges to $+\infty$ whether you approach from the left or from the right. If I give you a big number, $N$, you'd be able to find a number greater than that by plugging in a value that is close to (but not equal) to $-2$. Are you using the epsilon-delta definitions of the limit to prove convergence and divergence?

Comment: @Tyler - Can you give an example of working that out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $$|a| = \begin{cases} a, & \mbox{if }  a \ge 0  \\ -a,  & \mbox{if } a < 0. \end{cases} $$

Using this definition you should be able to use normal limit techniques ($\epsilon-\delta$ or what have you)

Notice, of course, that your limit does not exist as $x$ approaches zero.